# how to render a button for just the first element in the array in react

Tags: reactjs

i want to render the download button just for the first element in the array and for the rest the button will be disabled

```
allFileVersions.map((eachVersion) => {
                return (
                  <div className="d-flex">
                    <div className="">versions:</div>
                    <div className="">{eachVersion.FileName}</div>
                    {/* <div>DOwnload</div> */}
                    <div
                      className={
                        "saveblue mg-r-10 " +
                        (allFileVersions[0]
                          ? ""
                          : "disabled")
                      }>
                      <i className="fas fa-download pd-r-5" /> Download</div>
                  </div>
                );
              })
```

Comment: you can make two components, one with the download button and the other one with it disabled and use array.map to render the disabled one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
allFileVersions.map((eachVersion, index) => {
  return (
    <div className="d-flex">
      <div className="">versions:</div>
      <div className="">{eachVersion.FileName}</div>
        {/* <div>DOwnload</div> */}
        <div className={"saveblue mg-r-10 " + (index === 0 ? "" : "disabled")}>
        <i className="fas fa-download pd-r-5" /> Download</div>
    </div>
  );
})
```

Comment: The null return is a bit redundant.

Comment: okay but for that i need to make two buttons but is that possible if i make a single button and switch it with the help of css by adding the class disabled?

Comment: What do you mean? What is the second button?

Comment: okay i got it now. i thought inplace of null i need to make a second button with disabled class. thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
allFileVersions.map((eachVersion,index) => {
                return (
                  <div className="d-flex">
                    <div className="">versions:</div>
                    <div className="">{eachVersion.FileName}</div>
                     {index === 0 && (
                            <div>DOwnload</div>
                      )}
                  
                    <div
                      className={
                        "saveblue mg-r-10 " +
                        (allFileVersions[0]
                          ? ""
                          : "disabled")
                      }>
                      <i className="fas fa-download pd-r-5" /> Download</div>
                  </div>
                );
              })
```

The map function gives you two values. The current item of the iteration and the current index. You can use the index to check if it's the first item.

Answer (score 0):

allFileVersions.map((eachVersion, index) => {
return (

versions:
{eachVersion.FileName}
{/* DOwnload */}
<div
className={
`saveblue mg-r-10 ${index === 0 ? "" : "disabled"}`
}>
 Download

);
})

Use the index for your logic instead.